# Javascript function IF statement not working

Tags: javascript

I am trying to add a class to a element when the value inside some inputs is empty and another when it isn't.

For some reason it is only landing on the else statement, I thought I was using the correct syntax to send multiple parameters but perhaps I was wrong.

Any ideas?

```
    var btnElementRegistro = document.getElementById('btnGuardar');
    btnElementRegistro.addEventListener('click' , validar);

function validar (){

var elementNombre = document.getElementById('txtNombre'),
    elementApellido1 = document.getElementById('txtApellido1'),
    elementCel = document.getElementById('numCelular'); 


    addClass(txtNombre,txtApellido1,numCelular);


}

function addClass(pName, pApellido, pCel){

if(pName.value === '' && pApellido === '' && pCel ===''){

    pName.className = "error";
    pApellido.className = "error";
    pCel.className = "error";

}else{
    pName.className = "noError";
    pApellido.className = "noError";
    pCel.className = "noError";


   }

 }
```

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT: I wanted to use if/else so that I could call another function to display a div(PopUp) when .noError was added.**

```
var elementoVerInfo = document.getElementById('btnGuardar'),
elementoBotonCerrar = document.getElementById('btnCerrar');

elementoVerInfo.addEventListener('click', function () {
displayPopUp('popUpCorrecto2');
});

elementoBotonCerrar.addEventListener('click', function () {
hidePopUp('popUpCorrecto2');
});

function displayPopUp(pIdDivToShow){
var fElementDivToShow = document.getElementById(pIdDivToShow),
newClass ='';
newClass = fElementDivToShow.className.replace('hide','');
fElementDivToShow.className = newClass + ' show';
}

function hidePopUp(pIdDivToShow){
var fElementDivToShow = document.getElementById(pIdDivToShow),
newClass ='';
newClass = fElementDivToShow.className.replace('show','');
fElementDivToShow.className = newClass + ' hide';
}
```

Comment: You should be passing the variable names - `addClass(elementNombre,elementApellido1 ,elementCel);` etc, not the ID's of those variables (`txtNombre`, `txtApellido1` and `numCelular`).

Comment: You're only checking the value of one of these variables... if(pName.value === '' && pApellido === '' && pCel ==='')

Comment: when you debug the app, are the parameters defined?  I'm guessing that one, or all of them are undefined and making your equality statements be false.

Comment: @AndrewNee I think you accidentally hit the "Add Comment" button rather than the "Post Your Answer" button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that you want something like this:

```
function validar (){

    var elementNombre = document.getElementById('txtNombre'),
        elementApellido1 = document.getElementById('txtApellido1'),
        elementCel = document.getElementById('numCelular'); 

    /*call it using the variables not the string identifiers.*/
    addClass(elementNombre, elementApellido1, elementCel);
    /*addClass(txtNombre,txtApellido1,numCelular);*/ /* wrong */        
}

function addClass(pName, pApellido, pCel){
    pName.className = pName.value === '' ? 'error' : 'noError';
    pApellido.className = pApellido.value === '' ? 'error' : 'noError';
    pCel.className = pCel.value === '' ? 'error' : 'noError';
}
```

**EDIT to answer question in comment**

> where could I add the call to the PopUp function once noError is
>   added?

If you want to add a function call then you have to use an `if` because `?` only allows single statements. Or you can do it as follows:

```
function addClass(pName, pApellido, pCel){
    pName.className = pName.value === '' ? 'error' : 'noError';
    pApellido.className = pApellido.value === '' ? 'error' : 'noError';
    pCel.className = pCel.value === '' ? 'error' : 'noError';

    if (pName.className === 'noError' && 
        pApellido.className === 'noError' && 
        pCel.className === 'noError'){
        callFunction(); /* call here the function you want */
    }
}
```

The above is the general approach because I don't know exactly if you want to call a function for each input or just once. If your intention is to call the function for each input then you can do it like this:

```
function addClass(pName, pApellido, pCel){
    if (pName.value === ''){ 
        pName.className = 'error';
    }
    else{
        pName.className = 'noError';
        displayPopUp(pName.id);
    }

    if (pApellido.value === ''){ 
        pApellido.className = 'error';
    }
    else{
        pApellido.className = 'noError';
        displayPopUp(pApellido.id);
    }

    if (pCel.value === ''){ 
        pCel.className = 'error';
    }
    else{
        pCel.className = 'noError';
        displayPopUp(pCel.id);
    }

}
```

Comment: Worked like a charm, thanks! For further reference what does ? does?

Comment: I was using a if/else because once the class noError was added I wanted to open a PopUp using the code I added to the edit. In snipped of code, where could I add the call to the PopUp function once noError is added?

Comment: @CodeGrasshopper It's a shortcut for `if-then-else`. The part before `?` is the condition, after `?` goes `then` branch, and after `:` `else` branch.

Answer (score 1):

This is the issue:

```
var elementNombre = document.getElementById('txtNombre'),
elementApellido1 = document.getElementById('txtApellido1'),
elementCel = document.getElementById('numCelular'); 

addClass(txtNombre,txtApellido1,numCelular);
```

`txtNombre`, `txtApellido1` and `numCelular` are the element ID's, not the variable names.

You should be passing the variable names you've defined:

```
addClass(elementNombre, elementApellido1, elementCel);
```

Comment: Thanks! I see that I made a mistake there, nevertheless it isn't working. It still add the noError class.

Comment: @CodeGrasshopper Are you sure the input elements are completely empty (have you tried console.logging them)? Could you throw me a quick jsFiddle showing the issue?

Comment: I managed to patch it up using agarwean's solution. Thought it puzzles me why yours didn't work as looking at the code it seems it should. If you want I can still make a fiddle out of this one.

Comment: @CodeGrasshopper It's probably because your question isn't worded properly. Your first sentence states that you would like to add the class if all the inputs are empty, while the answer you've ticked add's the class one by one.